# Is "А чему она должна научиться?" correct

Tags: перевод

Is the sentence "А чему она должна научиться?" correct? (Should be "and what must she learn?")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this looks correct, meaning can be understood from English translation you provided pretty acurately. This can be used as a response to something like:

> – Она пошла в школу с углублённым изучением английского языка.
>
> – А чему она должна [там] научиться?
>
> – Не только грамматике, но и разговорной речи.

Which is:

> – She enrolled to school majoring in English.
>
> – And what will she learn [there]?
>
> – Not only grammar, but also speaking.

Or:

> – Она не сможет работать, пока не пройдёт обучение.
>
> – А чему она должна научиться?

Translation:

> – She won't be able to work before she undergoes training.
>
> – And what must she learn?